# How to simulate random paths of a non-homogeneous continuous-time Markov process with discrete state space for a given infinitesimal generator matrix?

Tags: st.statistics, stochastic-processes

1. Let $X=(X_{t},\,t \in T)$ be a non-homogeneous, continuous time Markov process with a finite state space $S=\{1,...,K\}$.
2. Let $\alpha_{i,j}(t)$ be the hazard rates of some $\varGamma$-distributed random variables.

> **My question:** How can I simulate random paths of the Markov process with a transition intensity matrix which is built with the above hazard rates $\alpha_{i,j}(t)$?

For example:
$S=\{1,2,3,4\}$ with given $\alpha_{i,j}(t)$ with $i,j \in S$.

Any idea is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you're in state $i$. For each $j$, let $X_j$ be an independent Exponential random variable with mean 1.

Now solve
$\int_{0}^{T_j}\alpha_{i,j}(t)\ dt=X_j$ for each $i$. Whichever of the $T_j$'s is smallest, you jump from state $i$ to state $j$ at time $T_j$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Do you have a reference (a book or paper) for your answer.

I will now apply this procedure in MATHEMATICA. Again, thank you!

Comment: No sorry I don't. Something like this has been in the back of my mind for a while. You can check it though: compute the probability that there's a transition from $i$ to $j$ in the time interval $(t,t+dt)$ conditioned that there has been no transition up to time t. 

Comment: I tested it with constant transition intensities alpha and it works fine. For general alpha's as described above, it seems that it does not work correctly. Maybe I make a mistake. 

However, I will now apply your method to simulate a 3-state model (illness-death model). In this case, the analytical solution is known and will compare it with numerical results.

Comment: It works pretty fine with the reduced model. 

I generalized the model and solved the corresponding Chapman-Kolmogorov equation system and everything works pretty fine.

Thank you VERY much, 
with best wishes
Wolfgang